# Why my fans count number, in my like button changed to zero?

Tags: facebook

I'm having fan page on facebook, for my website. On my website I've put like button linked to my fanpage. The fans count was showing my fans on fanpage page. Yesterday this number went to zero. Other plugin - like box is showing correct number of fans. This problem is only affecting like button plugin.

I believe this is not my code problem, as when I'm using facebook dev like button generator it shows zero fans for fanpage url. Fan likebox is working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know problem and there is a bug report about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/657504371028995/

You can subscribe there to be updated about this issue.

Comment: The correct link for the bug report is the following https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/657504371028995/